# Syntax highlight for the Swift programming language

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Recently Apple announced the Swift language to be open sourced later this year. I noticed that google prettifier, which is used in eg. stack overflow to post code snippets, is not yet been adapted with Swift language specification. I checked the GitHub project [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) and it seems not present in the source sections. I posted an issue to ask for this extensions [issue380](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/380)

I don't know if any one out there already worked on a prettifier extension for Swift but I think it would be nice to have this new language integrated in the prettifier to post correctly coloured Swift snippets. Not only for stack overflow but also as use of personal sites, blogs,...

Just got mail today on 04/08/2015 so this can't be duplicated anymore ;-)

[code-prettify] Add Swift Support (#383)

This pull request adds Swift to the list of languages that can be prettyprinted. It should be noted that it does not support highlighting the contents of string interpolation expressions, due to the high complexity of correctly classifying such structures with just a lexer.

You can view, comment on, or merge this pull request online at:

https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/383

Commit Summary

Add a file for the Swift language lexer definition.
Add support for whitespace and comments
Add highlighting for Swift keywords
Add highlighting for string literals
Add shortcut for string literal detection to Swift
Add integer literal support for Swift
Fixes and improvements for Swift
Add floating point literal support for Swift.
Add punctuation support for Swift
Add punctuation support for Swift
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:chrisrecher/code-prettify
Add type support for Swift, to the fullest extent possible in a lexer
Remove unnecessary comments
File Changes

A src/lang-swift.js (59)
Patch Links:

https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/383.patch
https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/383.diff

Comment: I 'm just notified of the fact that latest pull will contain swift: